# La parola "tiella" è dialettale? Qual è l'origine di questo vocabolo?

Tags: etymology, regional

Ho trovato la parola "tiella" nel menù di un ristorante italiano (napoletano, infatti) per riferirsi a un antipasto composto da arancini, mozzarella in carrozza, panzarotti... che viene servito in un recipiente piatto.

Mi piacerebbe sapere se questa parola è dialettale e qual è la sua origine. Per curiosità vorrei sapere se l'origine di questo vocabolo ha qualcosa a che vedere con quello della parola catalana "teula".

Comment: Questa è stata la mia prima domanda su Italian.SE: non sapevo neanche dell'esistenza del vocabolario Treccani!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Secondo la [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/tiella/) "tièlla" deriva dal latino "tegella", diminutivo di "tegŭla", e si tratta di una forma antica e regionale (centro-meridionale) per "teglia".

Per estensione, o più precisamente per metonimia, è anche il nome della specialità gastronomica della domanda sù ed è «diffusa in molte località dell’Italia centro-meridionale (con notevoli varianti anche nell’ambito di una stessa regione)».

Nel Lazio e in Campania viene chiamata "tiella" mentre è detta "tigella" a Modena, "tièed" in Puglia, "tijella" in Abruzzo ([fonte](http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiella)).

Anche "[teula](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/teula)" deriva dal latino "tegŭla", [qui](http://ca.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teula) apparentemente proprio nel significato di "tegola".

Comment: Grazie mille, ma secondo i dizionari, la parola latina "tegŭla" significa proprio "tegola". Mi domando cosa abbia a che vedere una "teglia" con una "tegola": forse è la forma piuttosto piatta...

Comment: Charo, "tegella" significa "piccola tegola"; "tegula" invece significa proprio "tegola". [La teglia](http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teglia) è detta "piccola tegola" per la forma a "coperchio", come la tegola. Questo risponde alla tua domanda?

Comment: non sono certo dell'identificazione della tiella con la tigella. Il De Mauro dà come secondo significato «TS gastr. torta rustica ripiena spec. di verdure, tipica della cucina centromeridionale» e la tigella non è ripiena...

Comment: @randomatlabuser: Grazie! Possibilmente hai ragione. Wikipedia afferma che una "teglia" ha una forma simile a quello di un "embrice romano". Ho trovato che in catalano l'"embrice romano" viene chiamato proprio ["tègula"](http://ca.wikipedia.org/wiki/T%C3%A8gula).

Comment: @mau: Nel ristorante italiano di cui ho parlato nella mia domanda, la "tiella" è un antipasto (composto da arancini, mozzarella in carrozza, panzarotti...) che viene servito in un recipiente piatto che assomiglia molto a questa immagine della ["tegula"](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Tegula_02.png).

Comment: Da notare che la parola è stata "esportata" nel francese "Tielle", una specialità culinaria di Sète (villaggio composto principalmente da immigranti italiani), che a quanto pare [trova le sue origini a Gaeta](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tielle). Da notare tuttavia che questo piatto si discosta abbastanza da quello che hai descritto!

Comment: E Dante usa il vocabolo "tegghia" (*Inferno* XXIX, 74).

Answer (score 1):

Secondo il *Grande dizionario della lingua italiana* ([[1](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI20/00001034.jpg)] e [[2](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI20/00001035.jpg)]), la parola "tiella" è un regionalismo con il significato di "teglia". Nel contesto della domanda, però, potrebbe trattarsi del napoletano "tiella", che significa "padella". Questo vocabolario riporta questa etimologia per questo termine:

> =  Voce  di  area  centromerid.  (cfr.  napol. *tiella*  ‘padella’  e  bologn. *tiela* ‘teglia’),  deriv.  da  un  lat.  volg.  **tegĕlla*,  dimin.  del tardo *tēgŭla* (v. TEGLIA); il  D.E.I.  lo  attesta  per  la  prima  volta nel 1365 in un documento di Teramo.

Anche "teglia" proviene dal latino *tēgŭla* e, secondo l'articolo ["Dal latino all'italiano: una storia di parole"](https://www.academia.edu/42115999/Maurizio_Trifone_Dal_latino_all_italiano_una_storia_di_parole?email_work_card=view-paper) di Maurizio Trifone, questa derivazione avrebbe a che vedere con l'usanza di cuocere il cibo su una tegola:

> Il latino TĒGŬLA(M), derivato di TEGĔRE ‘coprire’, significava in origine ‘tegola’ e ha assunto poi il significato di ‘teglia’ per l'uso di mettere una tegola sul fuoco per cuocere il cibo. L'esito
>   *teglia* /'teʎʎa/ (da un precedente *tegghia* /'teggja/, con sincope della vocale postonica e 
>   successiva trasformazione del nesso intervocalico -GL- in /ggj/) è sicuramente popolare, come 
>   provano i diversi mutamenti fonetici a cui è andata incontro la base latina; l’allotropo *tegola* 
>   /'tegola/, senza la sincope della vocale postonica, può essere invece ritenuto semidotto.

Sul [*Gran Diccionari de la llengua catalana*](https://www.enciclopedia.cat/ec-gdlc-e00133627.xml) della Fundació Enciclopèdia Catalana possiamo trovare l'etimologia del vocabolo catalano "teula":

> del ll. *tegŭla*, íd., der. de *tegĕre* ‘cobrir; amagar; protegir’   1a font: s. XIV, Llull

Quindi, in effetti, "teula" e "tiella" sono etimologicamente imparentate.